# How would I show the formula for the volume of a pyramid?

Tags: calculus

How can I show that the formula for the volume of a pyramid with height $h$ and an equilateral triangle as a base with side length $a$ is given by $$v =\frac{\sqrt3a^2h}{12}\;?$$

I have been poking at this question for the past few days and have not much to show for it.

Comment: Why is this tagged differential equations?

Comment: Are you presupposing knowledge of integral calculus?

Comment: Fixed to just calculus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** It is convenient to put the pyramid on its side, with the apex at the origin. By using similar triangles you can find an expression for the area of cross-section of the pyramid "at" $x$. Then you can use the usual formula for the volume of a solid when areas of cross-section  are known.

**Added:** At some stage you will want to know the area of an equilateral triangle with side $s$. By using "special angles" (and in other ways) it can be shown that this area is $\dfrac{s^2\sqrt{3}}{4}$.

Answer (score 2):

The volume is given by

$V=\frac{1}{3}B\cdot h$

where $B$ is the area of the base and $h$ is the height of the pyramid.

Now, the base is an isosceles triangle of side length $a$. So, $B=\frac{\sqrt{3}a^2}{4}$, which is pretty easy to show. The result follows.